# Service is Listening on port, no firewall enabled, but port shows closed when attempting to connect externally

Tags: linux, networking, mongodb

I am running a MongoDB service on port 27017 on a server. Both of:

```
lsof -i
netstat -a
```

Show that port 27017 is listening. I can connect to the service locally, but when I try to connect from an external machine the connection is refused. Running nmap on the port locally shows it as open, but running externally shows closed. I have completely reset the iptables and allowed connection via port 27017, and ufw is disabled. The mongodb config is set to allow access from all ips. What am I missing here?

Comment: Please add Unix/Linux version, and the relevant `netstat` output to the question. It is also not clear wether this is a machine with a private IP address space, and if you are trying to connect to it from the Internet.

Comment: Also did you make sure that it is listening on its external ip address as well as the loopback address. Some netstat or lsof output would really help.

Comment: Please add the contents of the MongoDB config file also, you may have bindIp configured incorrectly (for example). The output of `iptables -L` and the information the others have asked for would help nail this down